# ASP.NET MVC4 return list<T> from view back to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and have the below situation. I need some help creating the proper model or view.

I have the below model at the moment.

```
public class ExtrasModel
{
    public List<ExtraItem> ExtraItems { get; set; }
    public DateTime FlightArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public PickupInfoType PickupInfo {get; set; }
}


public class ExtraItem
{
    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }
    public int ProdExtraId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public int CostType { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double TotalCost { get; set; }
}
```

List of extras will be fetched from the database.

This is how I have the View :

```
@foreach(var extra in Model.ExtrasList)
{
        <tr>
            <td>
                //Not sure what code to put here
                @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.ExtrasList, new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text", extra.Quantity), new { id = extra.ProdExtraId })
            </td>
            <td>@extra.Name</td>
            <td>@string.Format("{0} {1}", extra.Cost, extra.Currency)</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Now how to make the view return the model with the quantities selected for extras?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to put the elements in a form, that will be postback to the server, then you can create a custom editor template for your type. If you do this, then use Html.EditorFor with your enumerable.

Create a EditorTemplates folder in your view folder, then add a new strongly typed partial view. Name it ExtraItem. Put the markup in this view for each individual item in your enumerable.

When you use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=> x.ExtraItems)
```

You will get output like this:

```
<input id="ExtraItems_0__name" name="ExtraItems[0].name" type="hidden" value="aName">
```

Notice the array style name. When the form is posted back the server will recognise the enumerable correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Create an **EditorTemplate** for the `ExtraItem` Model.
Content of the Editor Template is basically the same like the content of your loop.

Replace the Loop with the following statement:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ExtraItems)
```

This should do it.